# How can get the data inputstream and write a file of the same type uploaded in the server side?

Tags: java, file, file-upload, file-io, inputstream

I want to read the data from **inputstream** and write into a file of the same type using Java (`@FormDataParam("fileupld") InputStream in`).

Let say the uploaded file is a `.txt` then I need to write into a `.txt` file,
if it is an `audio`, then need to write into an `audio` file,
if it is an `image`, then need to write into an `image`,
if it is an `.doc`, then need to write into an `.doc` etc.............

My code should accept any kind of file and write into its appropriate type.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Why not store the extension name in a variable when you open it like so:

```
String extension = FilenameUtils.getExtension(inputFile);
```

`FilenameUtils` is a part of the apache commons io library. Then when you are ready to write to the file, use the extension variable to create the new file:

```
File file = new File("C:/files/output." + extension);
DataOutputStream stream = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
```